# Qt QFileSystemWatcher on Windows

Tags: qt, qfilesystemwatcher

I have the following issue: I create a `QFileSystemWatcher` and it runs and works nicely on Linux, but no way on Windows 7. Can you spot anything in the code that might make it not to work?

Thx.

Here is the code to initialize it:

```
mConfigChangeWatcher = new QFileSystemWatcher();
mConfigChangeWatcher->addPath(config_file_name);

QObject::connect(mConfigChangeWatcher,
                 SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)),
                 this,
                 SLOT(configFileChanged(QString)));
```

and this is supposed to be the slot getting the work done:

```
void MyClass::configFileChanged(const QString &file)
{
    qDebug() << "Changed: " << file ;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the path has to be represented differently?

Comment: the path is like: `("C:/Users/fela/work/d_RTI-1638/build/Applications/Debug/conf/configuration.xml")` (this is the output from the mConfigChangeWatcher->files()

Comment: I wrote a simple application, and it works. Maybe for our case it has to do with the fact that we move the app to a different thread, and then somehow signals gets lost ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you check if the file is added to the watcher using `QFileSystemWatcher::files()` method after the first modification in the file do you get the correct list?

I was with the issue that some applications, when modifing a file, delete the old file from the system and write it again.

> Note that QFileSystemWatcher stops monitoring files once they have been renamed or removed from disk, and directories once they have been removed from disk.

I was using QFileSystemWatcher to watch an image file edited by Photoshop. Somehow the file gets removed from the list of files being watched.

Comment: thank you! I didn't even assume file can be deleted and then created when you save it is some application. This explains why my QFileSystemWatcher stops monitoring a file when I edit it

Comment: BTW, I still don't know a proper way to handle this problem. My workaround was to use a single shot timer and then add the file again to be monitored. This doesn't work for all cases but solves my problem at the time.

Comment: :) I used the exactly same workaround. The other workaround I was thinking about is to monitor the directory that holds the file. But the first one is simpler and works well for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it very fast.
Within the slot that manages the `fileChanged` signal I noted the path disappears from `files()`. I simply make a check and re-add it if necessary

```
if (! watcher_.files().contains(path))
{
    watcher_.addPath(path);
}
```

I hope this helps

Fabio